# Start and end of a period in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I'd like to return the value of the start and end of a data frame based on the data it contains. If there are only zeros than I would like to fill in the start and end column with NA.

Data structure:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Sample data:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3), A1 = c(1, 1,0), A2 = c(1, 1,0), A3 = c(0, 
1,0), A4 = c(0, 1,0), A5 = c(0, 1,0)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), A1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), A2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), A3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), A4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), A5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Sample code (does not work on O rows):

```
start <- names(df1)[-1][max.col(df1[-1], "first")]
end <- names(df1)[-1][max.col(df1[-1], "last")]
data.frame(ID = df1$ID, start, end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% pivot_longer(-ID) %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(s = cumsum(value)) %>% mutate(s = na_if(s,0)) %>% 
    transmute(start = str_c('A',min(s)), end = str_c('A',max(s))) %>% distinct()
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID start end  
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1 A1    A2   
2     2 A1    A5   
3     3 NA    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the base functions and a for-loop, you can loop through all the rows and note the lowest and highest column that contains 1. It would, however, not note any breaks in the streak. If your streak of `1` is interrupted by a `0`, this would not show in the result.

```
id = c()
start = c()
end = c()
for(i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  id = c(id,df$ID[i])
  row = df[i,-1]
  start = c(start,names(row)[min((1:length(row))[row==1])])
  end = c(end,names(row)[max((1:length(row))[row==1])])
}

out = data.frame(ID=id,
                 start=start,
                 end=end)
```

The output is:

```
> out
  ID start  end
1  1    A1   A2
2  2    A1   A5
3  3  <NA> <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% #rowwise() %>%
  summarise(start = list(names(cur_data())[as.logical(cur_data())]),
         end = unlist(map(start, ~last(.x))),
         start = unlist(map(start, ~first(.x))),
         .groups = 'drop')

#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      ID start end  
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 A1    A2   
#> 2     2 A1    A5   
#> 3     3 <NA>  <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Below a little program which might help. However, this will just work if you are sure that there are no zeros within a row of ones. Your example data and sample code suggest that.

```
#your data
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3), A1 = c(1, 1,0), A2 = c(1, 1,0), A3 = c(0, 1,0), A4 = c(0, 1,0), A5 = c(0, 1,0)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), A1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",  "collector")), A2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), A3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), A4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), A5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))

#use the library data.table
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.table(din)

#make a sum of by ID (by row)
df1[,sumUSE:=sum(.SD), by=ID]

#last
df1[,end:=names(df1)[(df1[,sumUSE]+1)]]
df1[end=="ID", end:=NA]

#first
df1[,start:=names(df1)[2]]
df1[is.na(end), start:=NA]

print(df1)
#   ID A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 sumUSE  end start
#1:  1  1  1  0  0  0      2   A2    A1
#2:  2  1  1  1  1  1      5   A5    A1
#3:  3  0  0  0  0  0      0 <NA>  <NA>
```